# How to check status of AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, stream, avplayer, status, rate

I thought that I could check the status of an AVPlayer simply by the property "rate".

This is how I create a player instance:

```
player = AVPlayer(URL: stream) // streaming from the internet
player!.play()
```

At some later point I would do something like this

```
println(player!.rate)
```

This is what I discovered:

- In Simulator I get "0.0" in case the player is not running or "1.0" if it is running.
- If I start the player but interrupt the internet connection it changes values from 1 to 0.
- However, on my iPhone the property keeps value 1 even if I enter Airplane Mode?!

Do you have any idea why that happens and how I could check the stream condition otherwise?

I have tried an observer so far:

```
player!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
```

But even the method "observeValueForKeyPath" does not get fired in my iPhone test case.

Comment: You can try to use player!.currentItem.addObserver and it should be fired.

Comment: Oh well, that would be embarassing... I'll check it out tomorrow, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not make it work with adding an observer on the currentItem as user @gabbler suggested.

However it helped using the notification center like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(
    AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification, 
    object: nil, 
    queue: nil, 
    usingBlock: { notification in
        self.stop()
    })
```

Note that stop() is a method in the same class which stops the stream as if a stop button were clicked.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [the Apple docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_8)
and scroll to the "**Key-Value Observing**" section. **Especially #3** in that section.

It helped me get my implementation to work. My resulting code looks like this:

```
//Global
var player = AVPlayer()

func setUpPlayer() {
    //...
    // Setting up your player code goes here
    self.player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
    //...
}

// catch changes to status
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    print("obsrved")
}
```

Comment: Small changes `override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        print("obsrved")

    }`